# Can't access to postgreSQL server

Tags: navicat

I'm having a trouble which I can't connect to my database using IP Address. It works fine when I access it to my local but the problem is the other PC can't connect to my server. I've been using postgre v11 and navicat v12. Is there any permission to setup in my device in order that the other devices can access to my database?  It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance

[image: Localhost][image: Using Ip]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the host settings of the database to access it from a foreign IP

Comment: This is my current host settings [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3f2N.png)  , what should I change? should I add another user?

Comment: yes you should add another user allowing it to connect to your ip or device with all privleges

Comment: It works on my phpmyadmin mysql but I've been using postgres and yet I can't find the add roles in pgAdmin 4 I've been following this documentation [link](https://chartio.com/learn/postgresql/create-a-user-with-pgadmin/)  but I can't find the steps to add user . When I right click Tablespace , new role was missing [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3mzS.png)

Comment: you have to change the pg_hba.conf file allowing the host using [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at two things if connections from remote hosts are being rejected.

First what is the value of the  parameter listen_addresses in the postgresql.conf file?  If it is set to:

```
listen_addresses='localhost'
```

It will be allow only local loopback connections.  Change this (for example to listen on all interfaces) to:

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

Next, check the pg_hba.conf file has a rule to allow connections from your remote client.  By default PostgreSQL will refuse these remote connections and they must be  whitelisted.  The following example entry would allow any user to connect to any database from 192.168.1.2 and they must supply the password

```
host    all        all             192.168.1.2/32     md5
```

Check out the  official PostgreSQL docs for this at:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: I tried this set up. But still fail to connect.

Comment: OK - have you restarted the PostgreSQL service after making those changes?   There is no firewall between these servers (you can ping and ssh between them)?